# How to extract social information from a given website?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, social-networking

I have a Website URL Like www.example.com

I want to collect social information from this website like : facebook url (facebook.com/example ), twitter url ( twitter.com/example ) etc., if available anywhere, at any page of website.

How to complete this task, suggest any tutorials, blogs, technologies ..

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't know exactly where (on which page of the website) those link are located, you probably want to base you spider on [`CrawlSpider`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider) class. Such spider lets you define rules for link extraction and navigation through the website. See this minimal example:

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'example.com'
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow_domains=('example.com', )), callback='parse_page', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_page(self, response):
        item = dict()
        item['page'] = response.url
        item['facebook_urls'] = response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "facebook.com")]/@href').extract()
        item['twitter_urls'] = response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "twitter.com")]/@href').extract()
        yield item
```

This spider will crawl all pages of `example.com` website and extract URLs containing `facebook.com` and `twitter.com`.

Comment: helpful, but i want social url of same website only. the problem occurs if website having multiple social urls of different domain ( websites ) nearly like blogs

Comment: It would be much easier if you specified the requirement in greater detail, on concrete example. Give a website and information you want to retrieve.

Comment: actually i have approx 10000 urls and i want to collect social address for all, so i want to do this !!

Comment: It suffices if you provide just a single example. I don't understand your original comment.

Answer (score 2):

```
import requests
from html_to_etree import parse_html_bytes
from extract_social_media import find_links_tree

res = requests.get('http://www.jpmorganchase.com')
tree = parse_html_bytes(res.content, res.headers.get('content-type'))

set(find_links_tree(tree))
```

Source: https://github.com/fluquid/extract-social-media

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you want to 
1. Search for links in Header/Footer of the html page layout. As that is the most common place for them.
2. You can cross reference with found links on the other pages of the same site.
3. You can check if name of site/organization is in the link. But this one is not reliable as name may differ abit or use absolutely strange handle.

That is all I can think of.